# Dangerous implicit conversion in emplace

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiles without any errors/warnings with gcc 6.3 (https://godbolt.org/g/sVZ8OH), but it contains a dangerous undefined behavior due to invalid memory access marked below. The root cause is the implicit conversion performed in emplace_back. Can anyone suggest a good way or best practices to avoid such bugs in code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(const int& i) : i{i} {}

  void foo() const { std::cout << i; }  // invalid memory access, as i is an invalid ref!!
  const int& i;
};

void bar(const double& d) {
  std::vector<Foo> fv;
  fv.emplace_back(d);
}
```

Comment: "Can anyone suggest a good way or best practices to avoid such bugs in code?" - avoid using references as members?

Comment: Foo{d} will be rejected by the compiler since {} initialization prevents implicit conversions.

Comment: @user2736667 oops, thankyou, comment deleted

Comment: What's emplace got to do with it? `fv.push_back(Foo(d));` has the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

If you are going to accept a const reference, but you *don't* want a reference to a temporary, declare an additional constructor with an rvalue reference argument - and delete it.

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(const int& i) : i{i} {}
  explicit Foo(const int&& i) = delete;  // This preferentially matches a reference to a
                                         // temporary, and compilation fails.

  void foo() const { std::cout << i; }  // invalid memory access, as i is an invalid ref!!
  const int& i;
};
```

(I am assuming that the actual problem is more complex than just an int.  For an int, holding it by value is the right answer.)

Comment: Is my assumption right that the parameter of type `double` from the `bar` function is implicitly casted to an int and then handed on to the default move constructor (which is either deleted or created on default by the compiler regarding the code provided in this thread..) ?

Comment: Not quite.  The `double` is indeed implicitly casted to an `int`.  The result of this cast is a temporary.  You can bind a const reference to a temporary (which was the OP's problem) but an rvalue reference is an even better match, so by deleting it, you get the desired error.  There is no move constructor involved.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone suggest a good way or best practices to avoid such bugs in code?

When your class stores a `const` reference to another object, you, as a programmer, are taking on the responsibility of making sure that you don't end up storing a dangling reference.

Unless you have a strong reason for storing a `const` reference, I would recommend storing a value.

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(const int& i) : i{i} {}

  void foo() const { std::cout << i; }
  int i;
};
```

Comment: Not just a const reference, surely any reference (or pointer).

Comment: @latedeveloper: Yes, but it's much easier to create a const reference to a temporary (which quickly becomes a dangling reference).  A non-const reference must be to an lvalue (which *can* become dangling - but it's less likely).

Comment: @latedeveloper, True. It's just that when a `double` is implicitly converted to an `int`, the temporary `int` can't be used in a function call that expects a non-`const` reference.