# Assignment of `const reference` member in explicit Constructor is not persistent using `std::vector`

Tags: c++, vector, reference, stl, constants

Playing around with the source code from [Dangerous implicit conversion in emplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402795/dangerous-implicit-conversion-in-emplace/41402930) I detected the following behavior:

```
struct Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(const int& i) : i(i) { 
        cout << "explicit int ctor called" << endl; }
    explicit Foo(const double& x) : i(i) { 
        cout << " explicit double ctor called // i : " << i << endl; }
    Foo(int&&) = delete; 
    Foo(double&&) = delete; 

    void foo() const { 
        cout << i << endl; }  
private:
    const int& i;
};

void bar(const double& d) {
    cout << "---------- create object vector ------------" << endl; 
    std::vector<Foo> fv;
    fv.emplace_back(d);
    fv[0].foo(); 

    cout << "---------- create object default ------------" << endl; 
    Foo f(d); 
    f.foo(); 
}

int main(){
    bar(5.0); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Prints:

```
---------- create object vector ------------
explicit double ctor called // i : 5
0
---------- create object default ------------
explicit double ctor called // i : 5
5
```

Thus in both cases the reference member gets correctly initialized during object creation, indicated by the outputs `i = 1`. But after calling the `foo()` function on both objects they yield different results. Retrieving the  recently emplaced Object from the vector prints `0` even thought it should print `1`. The other object performs right.

**Question** Why is the value of the const reference member not persistent when emplaced in the STL container ? (I am not interested in advices like "simply do not use (const) references as class members.)

Comment: Because: undefined behavior.

Comment: ok. why? For me, it looks like valid c++

Comment: `Foo::i` is a dangling reference.

Comment: Hmm. Is it? `5.0` lives the entire time.

Comment: It's initialized with the literal `1` in the `double` ctor though.

Comment: Oh, right. Wow, that's very subtle and very bad code.

Comment: Even if it weren't, that `5.0` would have to be converted to `int`, and `Foo::i` would be initialized with the temporary result (which would then immediately go out of scope).

Comment: yap, I edited the code above to make it more clear, my mistake it was so obscure in the first approach... anyway @MilesBudnek is right : changing the type of the member `i` from `const int&` to `const double&` providest correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
explicit Foo(const double& x) : i(i) {
```

The member reference `i` is initialized with itself, which [causes undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600152/initialising-a-reference-member-with-itself-legal).